# If $U$ is finite dimensional, then operator norm is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $M:U\to V$ be a linear map between normed vector space $U$ and $V$. We know $U$ is finite dimensional (but don't know about $V$). Define $\|M\| = \sup \{\|Mv\|\;:\;\|v\| = 1\}$. I want to show that $M$ is continuous and that $\|M\|$ is bounded.

There are two difficulties, first is that I know the proof for $M:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$. Continuity of $M$ is due to each entry of operator matrix of $M$ is linear thus continuous. I show unit sphere is compact and therefore continuous function obtains max. But now we are not in $\mathbb{R}$ any more, I don't know if unit sphere is compact or not.

The second difficulty is that $V$ might not be finite dimensional any more, so I can't represent $M$ in a matrix of finite dimension any more. Please help.

---

Further, not knowing if $U$ and $V$ are finite dimensional or not, I want to prove that $M$ continuous then $\|M\|$ finite.

Comment: Choose a basis in $U$ and estimate $\lVert Mu\rVert$ using this basis and the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Martin Let $\{e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $U$ such that $\|e_i\|=1$. $\forall u = \sum_{i = 1}^n u_ie_i.\;\|u\| = 1.\;\Longrightarrow |u_i|\le 1.$ Therefore $\|Mu\|\le \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i \|Me_i\|\le \sum_{i = 1}^n \|Me_i\|$ thus finite? But I'm worried that $|u_i|\le 1$ does not make sense since we are not in $\mathbb{R}$ and cannot use $|\cdot|$

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Exactly how do you justify $\lvert u_i \rvert \leq 1$? // For the added question: use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion for continuity with $\varepsilon = 1$: there is $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\lVert u - 0\rVert \leq \delta$ implies $\lVert Mu\rVert = \lVert Mu - M0\rVert \leq 1$

Comment: @Martin I don't know, because $F$ might not even be ordered. I learnt normed linear space in context of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I don't know how to go on from here technically $\|\sum_{i = 1}^n u_i M(e_i)\|$

Comment: But $\lvert u_i\rvert$ is a real number. Normed vector spaces usually means that we stick to real (or complex) scalars.

Comment: @Martin Ok I think I need to understand it as $d(u_i,0)$, is it correct?

Comment: If you write $u = \sum u_i e_i$ with respect to the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ then $u_i$ are scalars and $\lvert u_i\rvert$ is the usual absolute value of the scalar $u_i$.

Comment: @Martin I think this is what I don't understand, what does it mean to assign absolute value to elements from arbitrary number field? How is $||:F\to\mathbb{R}$ defined?

Comment: Check in your book or lecture notes: norms on vector spaces were most likely only defined for vector spaces over the fields of real or complex numbers. There is a general notion of [absolute values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_(algebra)) that make sense more generally, but in any case, it needs to be fixed for $F$.

Comment: @Martin Ok, that's what I was missing. Thanks. Also could you help me with the last sentence in my question?

Comment: My second comment contains a suggestion for this part of your question after the //

Comment: $V$ not being finite dimensional is not an issue. The dimension of the image is at most the dimension of the domain, and $U$ is finite dimensional. So you can just look at the image space of $M$ and give it natural subspace structure. It's easy to prove that $f: X \to Y$ with image contained in $Z \subseteq Y$ is continuous if and only if it's continuous as a map from $X$ to $Z$.

Comment: @kahen: This observation does not actually make the problem any simpler, does it?

Comment: @Martin depends. If OP has already proved that all norms on a finite-dimensional space are equivalent, then it does simplify things a bit. Everything reduces to the $\mathbb K^m \to \mathbb K^n$ case.

Comment: @kahen: But how is that case simpler? The first question itself is actually equivalent to the statement that all norms on $\mathbb{K}^n$ are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of the question:

Assume first that the norm on $U$ is given by $\lVert u \rVert_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lvert u_i \rvert $ where $u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i e_i$ with respect to the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$. With this norm we have that $\lVert u\rVert \leq 1$ implies $\lvert u_i\rvert \leq 1$. Then your estimate shows that $\lVert Mu \rVert \leq \sum \lvert u_i \rvert \lVert Me_i\rVert \leq C \lVert u\rVert_1$, where $C = \max\{\lVert Me_i\rVert \mid i=1,\dots,n\}$, so $\lVert M\rVert \leq C$.

Since $U$ is finite-dimensional, all norms on $U$ are equivalent. Therefore there is a constant $D \gt 0$ such that $\lVert u\rVert_1 \leq D \lVert u\rVert$. But then $\lVert Mu\rVert \leq C \lVert u\rVert_1 \leq CD \lVert u\rVert$, showing that $M$ is also bounded with respect to the original norm.

---

For the second question, use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion for continuity. Since $M$ is continuous, it is continuous at $0 \in U$. Therefore there is $\delta \gt 0$ such that $\lVert u - 0\rVert \leq \delta$ implies $\lVert Mu \rVert = \lVert Mu - M0\rVert \leq 1$. Thus, $\lVert u\rVert \leq 1$ implies $\lVert Mu\rVert \leq 1/\delta$ and hence $\lVert M \rVert \leq 1/\delta$.